# How to protect SQLite file by a password

Tags: sqlite, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET core web API using SQLite with EF CORE, I want to allow access to SQLite file DB only with a password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite doesn't support password protection by default, but you can use external encryption tools. For .net-core see the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/encryption